# The Role of $C_5$ plays in the structure of Self-complementary Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

$C_5$ is a special self-complementary graph, since it is the smallest counterexample to many conjectures. For example, $C_5$ is the smallest non-perfect graph. Even as a local structure, $C_5$ seems to have a deep influence on the structural properties of the self-complementary graphs. Here comes my questions: are there any known results showing what $C_5$-free self-complementary graphs look like? Are there any results showing how the existence of induced $C_5$ influences the structure of a self-complementary graph?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.6139.pdf) which discusses the following conjecture.

> Every self-complementary graph on $4k$ vertices either has an induced
> cycle on $5$ vertices, or a skew partition, or a symmetric partition.

A skew partition of $G$ is a partition of $V(G)$ into
$4$ sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ such that there are no edges between $A$ and $B$ and
all possible edge between $C$ and $D$.

A symmetric partition of $G$ is a partition of $V(G)$ into $4$ sets
$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ such that there are no edges between $A$, $D$ and $B$, $C$
and all possible edge between $A$, $B$ and $C$, $D$.